# Format String currency in java

Tags: java, string, formatting, decimal, string-formatting

How can I format this pattern: R$123.456.789,12 to this: 123456789.12?

What I tried:

```
 String valor_minimo = mSessao.getString("filtro_pedidos_valor").substring(2);
        String valor_maximo = mSessao.getString("filtro_pedidos_valor_maior").substring(2);

        DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.## EUR");
        dec.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        String credits = dec.format(valor_maximo);
```

But that does`t work.

Comment: *How* doesn't it work?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class java.lang.String

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#format-java.lang.Object-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.text.FieldPosition-), John.  It explains **exactly** when and why the `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown.

Comment: (As a note - this only compiles, IMO, because the `Format` class predates Java 1.5.  Otherwise, it would be parameterised, and you would not be able to pass a `String` into an instance that expects a `Number`.  It's a shame it has to fail at runtime like this, rather than give the standard compilation error.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit messy as my Java is rusty, but I believe what you're looking for is the `.replace` method. You're likely receiving the IllegalArgumentException because you're trying to format a String.

Give this a try, and rework as needed:

```
String number = "R$123.456.789,0";
number = number.replace(".", "");
number = number.replace(",", "."); //put this second so the previous line won't wipe out your period
number = number.replace("R", "");
number = number.replace("$", "");

//two ways you can do this. either create an instance of DecimalFormat, or call it anonymously.
//instance call:
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
//now parse the number and feed it to your decimal formatter
number = df.format(Double.parseDouble(number));

//anonymous call:
number = new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(Double.parseDouble(number));

//output test:
System.out.println(number);
```

Hope this helps!

Edited for a more complete and robust answer.

Answer (score 0):

you may use regex to clean up the format of your string

```
String cleanStr = inputStr.reaplaceAll("[^0-9,]","").reaplace(",",".");
```

so you will get simple 123456789.12, which you can parse to double and use as you want